# My project run only in simulator but do not work in device, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I create a polyline in map. and successfully create polyline in map view.
My problem is, This code run only simulator. do not work on device. I tried to many times but do not work on device.

Genrate the IPA and install in my device and crash my app. why? and simply run in simulator, why?

[I follow this link](https://github.com/manishnath/iOSPlotRoutesOnMap)

Why is this happining? please help
Thankyou

## my code

```
-(void) centerMapForCoordinateArray:(CLLocationCoordinate2D *)routes andCount:(int)count{
MKCoordinateRegion region;

CLLocationDegrees maxLat = -90;
CLLocationDegrees maxLon = -180;
CLLocationDegrees minLat = 90;
CLLocationDegrees minLon = 180;
for(int idx = 0; idx <count; idx++)
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLocation = routes[idx];
    if(currentLocation.latitude > maxLat)
        maxLat = currentLocation.latitude;
    if(currentLocation.latitude < minLat)
        minLat = currentLocation.latitude;
    if(currentLocation.longitude > maxLon)
        maxLon = currentLocation.longitude;
    if(currentLocation.longitude < minLon)
        minLon = currentLocation.longitude;
}


region.center.latitude     = (maxLat + minLat) / 2;
region.center.longitude    = (maxLon + minLon) / 2;
region.span.latitudeDelta  = maxLat - minLat;
region.span.longitudeDelta = maxLon - minLon;

[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
 }

- (MKPolyline *)polylineWithEncodedString:(NSString *)encodedString       {
const char *bytes = [encodedString UTF8String];
NSUInteger length = [encodedString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSUInteger idx = 0;

NSUInteger count = length / 4;
CLLocationCoordinate2D *coords = calloc(count, sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
NSUInteger coordIdx = 0;

float latitude = 0;
float longitude = 0;
while (idx < length) {
    char byte = 0;
    int res = 0;
    char shift = 0;
    
    do {
        byte = bytes[idx++] - 63;
        res |= (byte & 0x1F) << shift;
        shift += 5;
    } while (byte >= 0x20);
    
    float deltaLat = ((res & 1) ? ~(res >> 1) : (res >> 1));
    latitude += deltaLat;
    
    shift = 0;
    res = 0;
    
    do {
        byte = bytes[idx++] - 0x3F;
        res |= (byte & 0x1F) << shift;
        shift += 5;
    } while (byte >= 0x20);
    
    float deltaLon = ((res & 1) ? ~(res >> 1) : (res >> 1));
    longitude += deltaLon;
    
    float finalLat = latitude * 1E-5;
    float finalLon = longitude * 1E-5;
    
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(finalLat, finalLon);
    coords[coordIdx++] = coord;
    
    if (coordIdx == count) {
        NSUInteger newCount = count + 10;
        coords = realloc(coords, newCount * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));
        count = newCount;
    }
 }

MKPolyline *polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coords count:coordIdx];
free(coords);

return polyline;
}


- (void)getDirections {
//Cross country
//37.705553,-122.372074 to 25.883937,-80.223026


//Home to work
//37.7577,-122.4376 to 37.764473,-122.399639

CLLocation *newLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:22.7001469 longitude:75.8758194];
MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude);
annotation.title = @"You";
[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];

CLLocation *keyPlace = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:22.6924483 longitude:75.8653895];
MKPointAnnotation *endannotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
endannotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(keyPlace.coordinate.latitude, keyPlace.coordinate.longitude);
endannotation.title = @"School";
[self.mapView addAnnotation:endannotation];

CLLocationCoordinate2D endCoordinate;

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=false&mode=driving", newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude, keyPlace.coordinate.latitude, keyPlace.coordinate.longitude]];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *responseData =  [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];



if (!error) {
    NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
      NSLog(@"response == %@",responseDict);
    if ([[responseDict valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"ZERO_RESULTS"]) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                    message:@"Could not route path from your current location"
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
        return;
    }
    int points_count = 0;
    if ([[responseDict objectForKey:@"routes"] count])
        points_count = [[[[[[responseDict objectForKey:@"routes"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"legs"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"steps"] count];
    
    
    if (!points_count) {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                    message:@"Could not route path from your current location"
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
        return;
    }
    CLLocationCoordinate2D points[points_count];
    NSLog(@"routes %@", [[[[responseDict objectForKey:@"routes"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"] objectForKey:@"points"]
          );
    MKPolyline *polyline = [self polylineWithEncodedString:[[[[responseDict objectForKey:@"routes"] objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"] objectForKey:@"points"]];
    [self.mapView addOverlay:polyline];
    int j = 0;
    NSArray *steps = nil;
    if (points_count && [[[[responseDict objectForKey:@"routes"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"legs"] count])
        steps = [[[[[responseDict objectForKey:@"routes"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"legs"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"steps"];
    for (int i = 0; i < points_count; i++) {
        
        double st_lat = [[[[steps objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"start_location"] valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
        double st_lon = [[[[steps objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"start_location"] valueForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];
        //NSLog(@"lat lon: %f %f", st_lat, st_lon);
        if (st_lat > 0.0f && st_lon > 0.0f) {
            points[j] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(st_lat, st_lon);
            j++;
        }
        double end_lat = [[[[steps objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"end_location"] valueForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
        double end_lon = [[[[steps objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"end_location"] valueForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];
        
        //NSLog(@"lat %f lng %f",end_lat,end_lon);
        //if (end_lat > 0.0f && end_lon > 0.0f) {
        points[j] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(end_lat, end_lon);
        endCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(end_lat, end_lon);
        j++;
        //}
    }
    NSLog(@"points Count %d",points_count);
    //        MKPolyline *polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:points count:points_count];
    //        [self.mapView addOverlay:polyline];
    [self centerMapForCoordinateArray:points andCount:points_count];
}
}

#pragma mark - MapKit
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
MKPinAnnotationView *annView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"currentloc"];
annView.canShowCallout = YES;
annView.animatesDrop = YES;
return annView;
}

- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
        viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {
MKPolylineView *overlayView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];

overlayView.lineWidth = 5;
overlayView.strokeColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
overlayView.fillColor = [[UIColor purpleColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];
return overlayView;
}
```

Comment: What is the reason of crash? Check log and paste. That would be helpful to trace the issue.

Comment: device do not attached to my system so i create IPA and install in my device. so how could find reason?

Comment: @Janmenjaya please download reference link and check issues. thank you

Comment: @DivankKumawat Code is Fine no Crash, when i run your code in my Device (iPad) i think Crash is happen some other Reason.

Comment: @ChiragDjinjuwadiya please send your project file in dropbox url

Comment: @ChiragDjinjuwadiya please change lat long after run in your device. this reason crash app.

Comment: @DivankKumawat Check this https://ufile.io/7e16

Comment: @ChiragDjinjuwadiya :( why to crash in my device. my iphone 5s an iphone 6 both device crash app

Comment: Add NSAppTransportSecurity key in your project

Comment: @ChiragDjinjuwadiya Please guid and help. Please suggest any other tutorial.

Comment: Which lat long you use?

Comment: @ChiragDjinjuwadiya (22.7196,75.8577),( 22.6133,75.6823)

Comment: prev. my project ViewController.m replace with this new https://ufile.io/7328

Comment: @ChiragDjinjuwadiya ok wait please attached your file in my project

Comment: @ChiragDjinjuwadiya same issues run only simulator but not in device :(

Comment: which simulator you test? and which iOS Version of simulator

Comment: @ChiragDjinjuwadiya iphone 6 and ios 9.3

Answer (score 0):

I go through your code and run in simulator, it will show warning CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9824) NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824), so i think you miss the NSAppTransportSecurity key in your plist.

Comment: I added NSAppTransportSecurity key in my plist, but not resolve my problem. :(

Comment: Please guid and help. Please suggest any other tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems with certificate try by setting development certificates and check provisioning profile.

Set the proper certificates and provisioning profile in build setting/target then check.

More detail read:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html

Comment: certificates and provisioning profile and all process is correct. First thing is i changed lat long then create IPA and run in device so that time crash my app. and second thing is do not change lat long after create IPA and run in device. that time proper work in device.

Comment: Please guid and help. Please suggest any other tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Run in iphone4s or 5 Simulator, if it crash in simulator than change

```
points[j] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(end_lat, end_lon);
endCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(end_lat, end_lon);
j++;
```

**With**

```
if (j<=points_count) {
    points[j] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(end_lat, end_lon);
    endCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(end_lat, end_lon);
    j++;
}
```

Why? Because 
we declare  `CLLocationCoordinate2D points[points_count];`
So max `Coordinate2D` is `points_count`
but some latitude longitude `j` value is higher than the `points_count` so we have to put if condition for `j`

Check it and let me know it it solve your problem or not.

Comment: Ok I checked please wait some time, Thanks for give your Precious Time :)

Comment: No, same issue? please suggest another tutorial

Comment: I have installed IPA in my device and run after crash? How?

Comment: did you check in iphone4s or 5 Simulator?

Comment: yes i checked in  iphone4s or 5 Simulator are worked proper but do not work in device.

Comment: Than run app with device attach, and put crash log in question.

Comment: I tried but do not attached my device in itunes and xcode, because i am using a virtual MacOS. so do not show device in macos. please suggest some other way, how can do this?