# How to draw PolyLine in MapView ios9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have create a PolyLine in MapView. I tried to many times but did not draw. Ones a draw polyLine but that case run only simulator, I run in device and crash my app. and I already post my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040637/my-project-run-only-in-simulator-but-do-not-work-in-device-why/40056340#40056340)

I tried to many times and using lots of tutorials,  please suggest any other tutorial.

I want to create a PolyLine in MapView using google direction URL. Starting point is my device location and end point is any lat long. so both points in centre draw a polyLine. That means create a root map starting point to end point draw a PolyLine.

Please help, Thank you

Comment: addOverlay on main queue .

Comment: ... and implement [`mapView:rendererForOverlay:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452203-mapview?language=objc), instantiating and configuring a [`MKPolylineRenderer`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkpolylinerenderer?language=objc).

Answer (score 1):

you can use google api for this

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin

in this api you have to pass lat log of your locations like this methode

```
  -(NSArray*) calculateRoutes
    {


            NSString *baseUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%f,%f&destination=%f,%f&sensor=true",currentlatitude,currentlongitude,destination lat,destination log];

            NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseUrl]];
            if (data) {

                NSDictionary *direction_dictionary=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
                if (direction_dictionary) {
                    if ([[direction_dictionary valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {
                        NSArray *routes_array=[direction_dictionary valueForKey:@"routes"];
                        if (routes_array) {
                            NSString *poinstEncoded_String=[[[routes_array firstObject] valueForKey:@"overview_polyline"] valueForKey:@"points"];
                            routes = [self decodePolyLine:[poinstEncoded_String mutableCopy]];
                            NSInteger numberOfSteps = routes.count;

                            CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[numberOfSteps];
                            for (NSInteger index = 0; index < numberOfSteps; index++)
                            {
                                CLLocation *location = [routes objectAtIndex:index];
                                CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = location.coordinate;
                                coordinates[index] = coordinate;
                            }
                            MKPolyline *polyLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinates count:numberOfSteps];

                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                [self.MapVw addOverlay:polyLine];

                                // add polyline here to your mapview
                            });

                        }
                    }
                }




            }


    }

-(NSMutableArray *)decodePolyLine: (NSMutableString *)encoded
{

        [encoded replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\" options:NSLiteralSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, [encoded length])];
        NSInteger len = [encoded length];
        NSInteger index = 0;
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSInteger lat=0;
        NSInteger lng=0;
        while (index < len)
        {
            NSInteger b;
            NSInteger shift = 0;
            NSInteger result = 0;
            do
            {
                b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            NSInteger dlat = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;
            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do
            {
                b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            NSInteger dlng = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;
            NSNumber *latitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lat * 1e-5];
            NSNumber *longitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lng * 1e-5];
            CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude floatValue] longitude:[longitude floatValue]];
            [array addObject:loc];
        }
        return array;


}
```

Comment: routes is a global NSMutableArray .

Comment: and use of undeclared identifier " SSGlobleFuntions". in this line ,  routes = [SSGlobleFuntions decodePolyLine:[poinstEncoded_String mutableCopy]];

Comment: @DivankKumawat i already mention that routes is a array object. declare it in your h file.

Comment: decodePolyLine  some issues please wait. send my project url and please ones check my mistake.

Comment: @DivankKumawat what url?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/23bkyam73hp8xjt/polyline.zip?dl=0    please download and see

Comment: In this URL my Project with your code. some error show in this project, please check and suggest. where i am wrong ?

Comment: are you there? I am still waiting you response

Comment: @DivankKumawat i can't download your code i am doing some work.

Comment: ok whenever you free after solve my problem. please i request to you

Comment: please help i am still waiting for your replay

Comment: no visible @interface for 'viewcontroller' declares the selector 'decode polyline' error show bellow in this line  " routes = [self decodePolyLine:[poinstEncoded_String mutableCopy]];"

Answer (score 0):

After getting response (Full example http://way2ios.com/development/ios-development-2/iphone-2/draw-polygon-mkmapview-stylus/):

```
   – (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id )overlay

 {

MKPolygonView *polygonView = [[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithPolygon:overlay];

polygonView.lineWidth = 5;

polygonView.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];

polygonView.fillColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:191 blue:255 alpha:0.5];

 mapView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

 return polygonView;

 }
```

Check these also : 
https://github.com/kadirpekel/MapWithRoutes and https://github.com/versluis/MapViewLines

Comment: You've copied code that has lost much of its spacing. E.g. `[MKPolygonViewalloc]` should be `[MKPolygonView alloc]`. Etc. Also, he's using a polyline, not a polygon, so you really want `MKPolylineView`, or, better, `MKPolylineRenderer`. And you don't want `fillColor`. Also, `viewForOverlay` has been replaced with `rendererForOverlay`...

Comment: not working this project please check ones  https://github.com/kadirpekel/MapWithRoutes

Comment: @Rob, i already shown the link i have taken from it. Thanks for your concern.